# What is the code behind this javascript?

Tags: javascript, portfolio

I'm trying to find out how they were able to create this site. http://www.cpeople.ru, i am trying to build my portfolio to look something like it. Particularly, I want the slider effect of the menu. Please help me out. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the source code, it's quite open. They're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) with the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) and [Mousewheel](http://brandonaaron.net) plugins. On top they have two custom scripts called [`f.js`](http://www.cpeople.ru/js/f.js) and [`portfolio.js`](http://www.cpeople.ru/js/portfolio.js), which are plainly readable as is.

Comment: I've seen the code. I'm trying to figure out how they are adding the content. Any tips in understanding javascript? My only experience with javascript is using jquery library and plugins so I don't really understand the code that much.

Comment: @Kat I'd recommend you first get to know Javascript. Follow W3 Schools or any similar tutorials for the beginning, consult the Mozilla reference or Crockford for some more advanced points. Then play around with some of the jQuery UI widgets and plain jQuery effects. Tons of documentation available for both. You'll get the idea eventually, then you can add individual pieces together to make a site such as cpeople. They're really only hiding and showing content dynamically with some slide effects. It's not too complicated, just well put together.

Comment: Cool! Thanks deceze! I guess all I really have to do is get familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into free JavaScript frameworks, particularly jQuery UI.  jQuery can do plenty of special effects, and it's quite easy to use.

If you look at the source of the linked webpage, you can see it uses jQuery and two jQuery plugins, jCarousel and mousewheel.

Be sure not to copy swathes of code from existing websites (unless it is expressly permitted, as is the case with jQuery), as that would be copyright infringement.

Comment: This list comparing JavaScript frameworks might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Comment: Thanks Joey, I wonder if there is a way I can find out how to do this effect without copying swatches from them. I don't know which part of their code does these effects. I want to somehow use jquery to create the menu nav that slides down and also the horzontal slide for the content. I am still quite new at this.

Comment: The answer is to start small.  Don't try to accomplish big things right away.  Play around with simpler objectives until you have a better understanding of things.

Answer (score 0):

Try [chrome sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae)  if you use google chrome.